# Shows Invalid Object Name in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am to very new to SQL Server and to the Stored Procedure. I tried to create a Stored Procedure for updating the table. I used the below statement in the stored procedure and executed it, worked fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateDB]
```

When I changed it to below code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateDB]
```

It shows in the work area like this,

[image]

But when I execute the stored procedure, it shows
[image]

I even checked, the created usp_UpadteDB Stored Procedure exists under the Stored Procedures folder and did refreshes too. What could this be?

Comment: It is the same database.

Comment: Are you saying that when you execute the ALTER PROCEDURE command, it works successfully?

Comment: Yes it executes successfully, but in the work area I see a red underline saying Invalid object name under name of Stored Procedure.

Comment: It's a well-known issue that sometimes the intellisense stops updating properly. You can generally fix it by CTRL-SHIFT-R (Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache)

Answer (score 2):

It got solved. I closed the SQL Server Management Studio and open again, checked the Stored Procedure. It is not showing Invalid object name any more.